# Recent document list for Word in W10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

In W7, when I click on start, it shows the most recent applications.  On mine, it shows Word with an arrow on the right.  If I click on word, the right pane expands to the most recently accessed word documents.

On W10, the Word icon just sits in the group of tiles.  It doesn't allow me to pick the most recent documents from the start.  I can only get there after I've opened word.

I have the same problem with Adobe Acrobat.

Is there a setting somewhere to switch to a W7 type menu which allows picking the document before opening the application?  It just saves a bit of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the list of recent files for Word, after clicking the start button, find Word or any other app. You then need to right-click on Word's icon. The list of recent documents will be shown.

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant - never thought of right clicking in the menu.